# Javascript, Ajax: How to visualize Boomerang.js results?

Tags: javascript, performance, web, visualization, boomerang

OK, I can add the code snippet to my testing page and pass in the parameters.  No problem.
How do I visualize the resulting parameters that get passed through the query string to my beacon url? I am stomped.

If I have in my testing page:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    BOOMR.init({
            beacon_url: "http://localhost/myvisualizationpage.php",
            site_domain: "http://localhost/mytestingpage.php",
            user_ip: "My Virtual Box Bridged IP Address",
            autorun: false
            });
</script>
```

How do I get this report (below) to be displayed in my "visualization" page?

```
This page took <x> ms to load
Other timers measured: 
t_resp = <x> ms
t_page = <x> ms
Your bandwidth to this server is <x>kbps (±<x>%)
Your latency to this server is <x>±<x>ms
Other parameters:
rt.start = navigation
bw_time = <x>
```

Check this link for reference: http://hacks.bluesmoon.info/boomerang/doc/howtos/howto-6.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at howtos.js in the documentation directory: https://developer.akamai.com/tools/boomerang/docs/tutorial-howtos.html

You can create an empty div called `results` and let howtos.js populate that div with the contents of the beacon.

Comment: That did it! Thank you. One thing though: the code from github should be checked out. The code that is currently working on my locahost is what I grabbed from your bluesmoon page. I mean, just the source code of the boomerang.js file. Yours works. The one I got form github doesn't.

Comment: I'll have to look into that.  I'm not sure when I last updated my hacks page actually.

Comment: Broken link now